# Effects of CVE-2017-9445?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, dns, vulnerability, global-adversary

- https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-9445
- http://openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/06/27/8
- https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3341-1/

What does this mean for tor browser users? How might this vuln be used against the tor browser? Could this be used to manipulate the first hop between users and the guard node?

(I know nothing about netsec, ossec -- obviously.)

Answer (score 1):

Tor doesn't use DNS.

Any DNS resolving is done at the exit node by the exit node, Tor Browser users are unaffected.

It might affect some exit nodes who haven't patched.